# Two sets of resistors with one switch

Tags: resistors, switches, hardware

My goal is to switch between two sets of five restistors. The goal was to use one switch to change the sets. By pushing one of the five switch the specific resistor of the set is connected between CRADLE_1 and CRADLE_2.

[image: first version, doesnt work]

Problem is that the two sets of restistors are interfering each other.
Example R1 should be 100 Ohm if SW_POWER switch is pressed. But R7, R8 and R2 are parallel to R1.

I'm little stuck and out of ideas. I could use a 5 Pole switch. But it would be nice to have a solution with 2 Pole switch. I still have a spare switch because my switch is 2 pole with 2 positions.

I will try to solve the problem with some diodes. Here's a example with 10VDC and 10Ohm that should give 1A of current. I get 0.91 because of voltage drop over the diode. I will try to add 10 diodes to my hardware and test it

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest redrawing the diagram first. Then look at how your referencing, eg R12 and R10 and R6 look to be in parallel with each other, R1 R2 R8 and R7 look to be in series and parallel.

Comment: Start with the initial requirement: What are the required resistances, and between what terminals? Are *two sets of five* given? Any predefined interconnections? State both in your question. Count your resistors - I see more than enough for *two sets of five*, `R12` being an indication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that this is some professional application that should be reliable and last a long time. In that case, just go for C&K DPST pushbutton momentary switches. Not only are they mechanically robust, pleasant looking, and will last a long time, but also they are offered in various pole counts - up to 4 or even 5!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJWGxZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use 3 pieces [DPDT signal relay](https://api.pim.na.industrial.panasonic.com/file_stream/main/fileversion/4514), coil controlled by your 2-position switch.

One momentary switch per common so you'd have room for 6 switches rather than 5 with 3 relays.

Electronic switches might be possible too, but it would depend heavily on the details of the application.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how.

Momentary push-button switches, with 2 'NO' contacts each, are required.

Only three resistors / set have been shown.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It appears (aka I'm guessing because there is no information on this) that cradle1 and cradle2 go to some kind of unipolar DC source and fixed impedance or constant-current circuit, and you are using the resulting voltage drop between cradle1 and cradle2 to encode which button is pressed.  IOW, the currents going through any resistor are the same polarity DC.

If that is correct, then 10 diodes could solve your problem.  Note that introducing a constant DC voltage drop into a resistor divider will affect the node voltages.  You will have to adjust the resistor values to get the same cradle voltages.

Comment: Hi AnalogKid. Yes you are right. We have two display hardware that use either cradle1 or cradle2 as a input device. The goal was to have a testbox that can switch between the two input devices. I will try to add some diodes and see if it still works... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The setup you show is a limited case of the general column/row matrix setup commonly used for multiplexed drive of everything from relay arrays to LCD displays.  In that general case there are n "row" signals, and m "column" signals, controlled via n & m row and column switches/FETs.

Typically one set of signals selectively connects to a voltage supply, and the other selectively connects to ground.

The desire is to activate the device at the cross-point, but not any of the others.

If you just connect bi-directional devices like resistors or relay coils at each cross-point, you will get main flow through the device at the crossing of the active row/column, but a lot of secondary flows.

For example, say you wanted to activate the device at (2,4).

Then you would apply power to Row(2) and ground Column(4), and the main flow would then be Row(2)->Column(4).

However, you will get secondary flows from Row(2)->Column(x), then Column(x)->Row(y) and finally Row(y)->Column(4).

In some cases this is not an issue (and 1/3 of the main voltage across each device may be okay), but in many case these "leak paths" are a problem.

The classic fix is to recognize that the desired path has current going Row->Column, whilst the "leak" paths have a middle step which goes Column->Row.  If you insert a diode in line with each of the bi-directional devices at the crossing point, you prevent this reverse flow and only the device at the direct cross-point is activated.

Looking at your case, assuming the signal is DC, and you compensate from the diode voltage drop, then adding a signal diode in line with each resistor will give you exactly the behaviour you are seeking.

(Btw, for matrix drive of LEDs as opposed to LCDs, the additional diodes aren't needed, as the LEDs inherently prevent backflow paths.)

This approach can also be expanded into the wonderful [Charlieplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing) scheme, which allows you to drive diode arrays with far few pins that you might expect, as long as each pin can be tri-stated.

[image: Charlieplex drive of LEDs][Image linked to Wikipedia article]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPltN7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Alternatively, you can use the second pole to "bridge the gap" between the sets of each bank.

Answer (score -3):

I think your gonna wanna try something like this

[image: PaintLazy]

Comment: Hi Jack. Thanks for your input. We still have the same problem that the second set of resistors interfering the first set of resistors.

Comment: If it's a mechanical SPST switch controlling the power lines the current shouldn't flow through the second set of resistors, if its a electronic switch then you'll get leakage and the resistors will act more like voltage dividers and you will get interference, in which case consider adding some diodes or using SPST switches instead of push buttons for output put control

Comment: This is the same circuit, just redrawn differentlly. If you would have used unique reference designators, I could describe the parallel paths in words.

Comment: This circuit doesn't isolate any of the resistors irrespective of any leakage current utilizing an electronic switch version.